# List files in folder - no output showing

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to loop through the files in a folder that have the extension `.jpg` or `.jpeg`.  This looks like it should work, but for some reason nothing is printing. When I run it, no compile errors, it just doesn't print anything to the Python console.

```
import os

def find_images(image_dir, extensions=None):
    default_extensions = ('jpg', 'jpeg')
    if extensions is None:
        extensions = default_extensions
    elif isinstance(extensions, str):
        extensions = (extensions,)
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(image_dir):
        for filename in filenames:
            print(filename, filename.split('.',1))
            if filename.split('.', 1)[-1].lower() in extensions:
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)


def main(image_dir=None):
    if image_dir is None:
        image_dir="D:/userName/Pictures/Gotham"
    find_images(image_dir)

main() #doesn't return anything in console
find_images("D:/userName/Pictures/Gotham", ) # also doesn't do anything...
```

All of the questions I tried to find online give the *method* of doing this (looping through files in a directory), but nothing is showing me *how* to use the path correctly, as that's what I think I'm not doing right.  There *are* pictures in the folder, I just can't seem to see why the script isn't listing the name for each.

I have also tried `image_dir=r'D:\userName\Pictures\Gotham'` and `...='D://userName//Pictures//Gotham'` to no avail.

edit: meant to add this.  This *does work*:

```
file_path = "D:/userName/Pictures/"
def list_images():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".jpg"):
                print(file, file.split('.',1))

list_images()
```

...so what am I overlooking in the above `find_images(...)`?

(FYI - I'm trying to implement things from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/165647/92133))

Comment: What do you get if you print out: `os.path.isdir(r"D:\userName\Pictures\Gotham")` ?

Comment: @zwer - same thing. See my edit though, it's odd...Even in `find_images` if I make the *first line* `image_dir = file_path`, nothing happens. Even doing `print("hi")`, nothing prints. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't notice the sneaky `yield` in your function... Well, you have made a generator function so it just returns an iterator when you call it - to get it to actually start executing you have to start iterating through it:

```
for image in find_images("D:/userName/Pictures/Gotham"):
    print(image)
```

or at least get the first element to start it:

```
first_result = next(find_images("D:/userName/Pictures/Gotham"))
```

Also, while I'm here, that's very unsafe way to check for an extension - if the file name has multiple dots (i.e. `my.image.jpg`) it won't be recognized. Use `str.endswith()` or slice from the back of the string instead of `str.split()` (or don't limit splits to one).

Comment: Oh man! That's it! I was wondering why in `main()` (in the Answer I linked to) was set up like so.  This makes a lot of sense, and actually taught me way more than I'd suspect a "simple" function would.  I'm still learning, but that's great, thanks a zillion!  Edit: Per your edit, what's a safer way? Is `if file[-4:] in extensions:` better?

Comment: A word of advice, tho - don't use generators for traversing through file lists without checking on the spot if the file still exists (e.g. once it passes your extension checks) with at least `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, filename))` before yielding the path back to the caller - `os.walk()` will have a cached list of files and not the current state (your generator can wait for hours) so it might happen that the file is gone by the time your generator gets to it. It's just safer to check for your files on the spot if there is a possibility of state change on your disks.

Comment: @BruceWayne - that (`filename[-3:] in extensions`) would work only if all your extensions were three letters long, otherwise you have to account for different lengths. There is a dedicated function that splits file name into base name and extension: [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) but you can achieve pretty much the same with right split: `filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1] in extensions` but that's unsafe - if there is no dot in the encountered filename it will raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I added `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, file)):` as the statement before `yield file`.  Well understood about checking for the file extension.  I'll look around, but I guess there's not a surefire way to get just the extension? I happen to know for a fact that they're all `jpg`, but say they're also `jpeg`. Currently I'm using `filename[-4:]` and checking if that's either `.jpg` or `jpeg` (note the missing period in jpeg)...I assume there's a better way, but that's a question for another day.  Thanks a ton for your help, again. Cheers!!